# JSON parsing with AFNetworking and model Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I am bit confused in fetching data and displaying data from json into my App using Model.

I am having this kind of json data :

```
{
result 
 [
    {
        key : value
        key : value
        key : value
    }
    {
        key : value
        key : value
        key : value
    }
 ]
```

}

I am trying this kind of code:

```
json = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            NSError *writeError = nil;
            NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:responseObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];

            NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                                options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                  error:&writeError];


            json = dic[@"Result"];
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i <= json.count; i++)
            {
                NSMutableArray *array = json[i];
                [json enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
                 {
                     // Dim = [[DimEntityFull alloc]initWithJSONDictionary:obj];
                      saveSearch = [[SaveSearchMaster alloc]initWithJSONDictionary:obj];
                 } ];
            }
```

I am using "AFNetworking" and I am trying to fetch data and store into model class and then display to custom cell labels.

How can I get it.

Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried logging the data at each stage of the extraction?

Comment: yes, but it's not working for me. i am bit confusing in how to store into the model class.

Comment: i know that arrayOfRecords = [jsonData objectForKey:@"result"]; and then cell.lblName.text = [[arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"name"]; is the right flow. but with model class how can i get the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    [self getUsersList];
}

-(void)getUsersList
{



    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];
    [manager POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.yourdomainname.com/getUserList"] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {

        //we will add Modal class objects of users in this array

        usersArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        //getting result dictionary from response
        NSDictionary *resultDictinary = [responseObject objectForKey:@"result"];
        for (NSDictionary *userDictionary in resultDictinary)
        {
            //allocating new user from the dictionary
            User *newUSer=[[User alloc]initWithDictionary:userDictionary];
            [usersArray addObject:newUSer];
        }

        //in users array, you have objects of User class

        //reload your tableview data
        [self.TableView reloadData];


    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

}
```

Now Create New file Called 'User'
in `User.h`

```
@interface User : NSObject
{
    NSString *userID;
    NSString *firstName;
    NSString *lastName;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *userID;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *lastName;

-(id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)sourceDictionary;


@end
```

in `User.m`
    #import "User.h"

```
@implementation User
@synthesize userID,firstName,lastName;


-(id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)sourceDictionary
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        self.firstName=[sourceDictionary valueForKey:@"firstName"];
        self.lastName=[sourceDictionary valueForKey:@"lastName"];
        self.userID=[sourceDictionary valueForKey:@"userID"];
    }
    return self;

}
@end
```

in your `numberOfRowsInSection`method
    `return usersArray.count;`

in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
User *user=(User *)[usersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
yourLabel.text=user.firstName;
```